# Como rodo uma imagem docker e assim que terminar o processo salvar no computador host o arquivo gerado dentro do container?

Tags: python, docker

Eu tenho um código que deve ser rodado em um container. Assim que ele rodar ele irá gerar um arquivo png. Segue o Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
COPY . /projeto
RUN apt update
RUN yes | apt install libeccodes-tools
RUN yes | apt install -y python3 && yes | apt install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install -r projeto/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /projeto
CMD python3 exemplo.py
```

exemplo.py:

```
import pandas as pd
ex = pd.DataFrame({'teste': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
ex.to_csv('exemplo.csv')
```

Build da imagem:

```
docker build -t meu_codigo .
```

Eu queria poder dar o comando abaixo e no processo de execução programado já salvar as imagens png(Ou qualquer arquivo que eu gerar) em alguma pasta do computador host.

```
docker run --rm meu_codigo
```

Como posso fazer isso? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: porque não cria um volume e use com o container? assim tudo que salvar no volume já vai estar disponível no computador host sem precisar de comandos para copiar

Comment: Essa imagem precisará ser rodada diariamente e reiniciada no fim do processo. São as diretrizes que a equipe de infra.

Comment: certo, mas não precisa apagar o volume certo? é a tal "pasta" que você quer salvar. Se quiser só fazer  um job que mova o conteúdo do volume para outro lugar

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer isso, voce tem que criar um volume, um link entre um diretório seu e um diretório dentro do container

Veja este exemplo, onde o comando vai gerar resultado dentro de um diretório `aux` e este está ligado a um diretório `output`

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.13.5
RUN mkdir aux
CMD echo "my text" > aux/output.txt
```

```
mkdir output
docker build . -t my-image
docker run --volume=$(pwd)/output:/aux my-image
cat output/output.txt
```

no seu caso:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
COPY . /projeto
RUN apt update
RUN yes | apt install libeccodes-tools
RUN yes | apt install -y python3 && yes | apt install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install -r projeto/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /projeto
CMD python3 exemplo.py
```

exemplo.py

```
import pandas as pd
ex = pd.DataFrame({'teste': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
ex.to_csv('aux/exemplo.csv')
```

```
mkdir output
docker build -t meu_codigo .
docker run --rm --volume=$(pwd)/output:/aux meu_codigo
cat output/exemplo.csv
```

Observe que caso o diretório não exista na imagem, ao se utilizar a opção volume ele é criado sem problemas